# Dynamically create an array of custom object types

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an array of Mat objects to store images and am getting warnings for using anything other than a statically typed number such as 10

```
int numberOfRects = boundRect.size();
Mat image_array[numberOfRects];
```

When I try this code I get an error stating Variable length array of non-POD element type 'cv::Mat'

Same goes for this code: `Mat image_array[boundRect.size()];`

How can I create an array of Mats based on the size of boundRect?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a dynamic array. This is a basic, but non-simple aspect of the language to learn, so I suggest you learn on some simple examples First.

You can create it like this

```
Mat *image_array = new Mat[numberOfRects];
```

But must delete it when you are done, otherwise there will be a memory leak.

```
delete[] image_array;
```

A better alternative is to use `std::vector`, which automatically deletes its contents. But a class must be copyable to be used in it, and I don't know what's allowed by this `Mat` class of yours. It would look like

```
std::vector<Mat> image_array(numberOfRects);
```

If `Mat` cannot be copied, the correct C++11 solution is to use a vector of smart pointers.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mat>> image_array(numberOfRects);
for (auto& mat : image_array)
{
    mat = std::make_unique<Mat>();
}
```